# Difference between declaring Routes in React Router v6 and v6.4+

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've tried searching that, however, couldn't really find whether using React Fragments is okay to achieve the same behavior as pre-v6.4?

```
const Routes6 = (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="posts" element={<Posts />}>
      <Route path="/posts/new" element={<NewPost />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
);
```

```
const routes64 = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts />}>
        <Route path="/posts/new" element={<NewPost />} />
      </Route>
    </>,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why using `React.Fragements` wouldn't work to implement the routes using the new RRDv6.4+ data router. A more conventional method that avoids the `React.Fragment` may be to use a root route on `"/"` and render the `Home` component on an index route.

Example:

```
const routes64 = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/">
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts />}>
        <Route path="new" element={<NewPost />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>,
  ),
);
```